# How can you set title and icon for a flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

What I'm trying to do is build a flutter web app that, when displayed in the browser, the tab shows an icon and a title (as currently it only shows the world icon and the localhost... title).

Actual Result :

[image: Actual Result]

Desired Result :

[image: Desired Result]

Edit:
I can now add the title, as this is set in the main function

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.white,),
      title: Text(_your title here_),
    )
    ...
  );
}
```

So, the only thing I need to edit is the favicon

Comment: appbar is not for the favicon and title beacause appbar in screen widget so you have to find out that widget in flutter

Comment: If you want to change title dynamically [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456687/how-to-dynamically-change-the-app-title-in-flutter-web/60456688#60456688)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In order to change the title to what you desire, you need to add the parameter `title` (Which is a `String`) to your `MaterialApp` widget.

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: "MyTitle", 
  home: MyHomeWidget());
```

Answer (score 23):

Assuming you already have a `favicon.ico` file, placing it inside the `your_project_dir/web` folder alongside `index.html` as shown below is enough for the browser to pick it up.

[image]

Following is the result of placing a `favicon.ico` in the `web` folder. Make sure to do a clean build.

[image]

In other case you can manually mention it using the `link` tag inside your `index.html` as explained here in this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use).

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically set the link and the title of the index.html page?
When opening a website built with Flutter, I need to get the business's details from my API, and set the favicon to be the business's logo & the title to be the name of the business.

Answer (score 15):

- **Edit title**

it is the simplest. just use the `Title` widget on  each page or directly inside the materialApp constructor and set title string key to the title  text you need.
like this:

```dart
...
Title(
  color: myColors, //not  important  in web but still required
  title: 'web  page title',
  child: myChildWidget,
),
...
```

- **Edit icon**

If your app is only for the web, use the `dart:html` library to perform change using DOM access.
something like this

```dart
import 'dart:html';
...
...
updateIcon(String assetIcon){
      LinkElement link = (document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") ??
          document.createElement('link')) as LinkElement;
      link.type = 'image/x-icon';
      link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
      link.href = assetIcon;
}
```

if your application is **multi-platform**, you need to **create separate main file** for the web like `main_web.dart`. and declare  the  previous  function inside  this  file.
Now, anywhere you need to set up the icon you  just  need to call the method after checking the platform using the keyword `kIsWeb`.

**Ex: change icon inside page**

```dart
...
initState(){
    super.initSate();
    if(kIsWeb){
      WebMixin.updateIcon("assets/home_icon.png"); //WebMixin is just a helper.  replace  it by your  one.
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `Title` widget. So undermentioned but it's super helpful.

Answer (score 13):

You could set the [onGenerateTitle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/onGenerateTitle.html) property of your [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) widget, and provide a callback function to build your title. The `onGenerateTitle` callback is called each time the `WidgetsApp` rebuilds. This is useful if you want the title of your page to change dynamically or if you want to produce a localized title.

```
MaterialApp(
  ...
  onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) {
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).myTitle;
  }
  ...
);
```

Comment: can you please tell me about AppLocatizations what it is?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization
You would need to configure your application to have localized pieces of text by doing something like this.

Answer (score 8):

If you're wondering how to change the app name on your device's homepage, you can update the "name" and "short_name" values in web/manifest.json:

```
"name": "Ideasky",
"short_name": "Ideasky",
```

Comment: How are name & short_name used differently? When are each used?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the `title` in the `MaterialApp` instance in your dart code, you should have a look at the `web/manifest.json` file also.

This contains the name of the PWA icon which is created when someone installs it on their device.