# How to dynamically change the App Title in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Web apps usually reflect the currently displayed content in the **tab's title**.

Supplying the [`title` parameter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/title.html) to a [`MaterialApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html) or [`WidgetsApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp-class.html) means that I cannot change it *without rebuilding the entire tree*, i.e. calling `setState` at the top level where I return my `MaterialApp`.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Web app title',
  ...,
)
```

---

I want to be able to change the **app title** from *anywhere* in the app at *any time*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Dynamic app title in Flutter

The **app title** can be **dynamically** changed *on all platforms* using [`SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setApplicationSwitcherDescription.html):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: 'Dynamic web app title',
      primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.value,
    ));


  return Container(...);
}
```

[image: Screen capture]

`SystemChrome` becomes available with [`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/services-library.html) and you want to call `setApplicationSwitcherDescription` in your **`build` method**.

This is also how [`Title`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Title-class.html) does it (see [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/449f4a6673f6d89609b078eb2b595dee62fd1c79/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/title.dart#L43)), which is the widget used by `WidgetsApp`, `MaterialApp`, etc.

Thus, you can also use a `Title` widget instead of accessing `SystemChrome` yourself:

```dart
@override
Widget build(Context context) {
  return Title(
    label: 'Dynamic app title',
    primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    child: ..,
  );
}
```

#### `label`

The `label` parameter is pretty straight forward: it maps exactly to what `title` is in your `MaterialApp` and just a `String`.

#### `primaryColor`

The `primaryColor` will determine the color the system might use in the application switcher, e.g. the title bar color in recents on Android.
This is an **`int` instead** of a `Color`, which is why you need to call [`Color.value`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/value.html) to convert your primary color to an integer.

### Interference with other `Title`s

You might ask yourself if calling `setApplicationSwitcherDescription` or inserting a `Title` widget when the `title` property on `MaterialApp` is set can cause any problems.
The answer is: **no** because the widget that is the deepest down in the tree will set the title. Essentially, even if the whole app rebuilds, your `setApplicationSwitcherDescription` will be called after that of `MaterialApp` assuming you are calling it in a child and therefore you will *override* the `MaterialApp` title.

Comment: @easeccy Your edits are being [discissed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406866/how-to-deal-with-obstrusive-edits).

Comment: using `Title` widget, how to revert title when back from another page using `Navigator.pop(context);`? or how to detect `onResume` event so I can call `SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription()`? I'm confused with this complexity for a simple need.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost 2 years late, but I found my decent solution for this. It's not that simple but pretty usable.

**main.dart**

inside `MaterialApp`, add `navigatorObservers`:

```
MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: "/welcome",
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/welcome':  (BuildContext context) => WelcomeScreen(),
    '/login':    (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen(),
    '/register': (BuildContext context) => RegisterScreen(),
  },
  // other codes ...
  navigatorObservers: [MyRouteObserver()],
  // other codes ...
);
```

and at the very bottom, add:

```
class MyRouteObserver extends RouteObserver<PageRoute<dynamic>> {
  void _setTitle(String what, PageRoute<dynamic> routeFrom, PageRoute<dynamic> routeTo) {
    final oldScreenName = routeFrom.settings.name;
    final newScreenName = routeTo.settings.name;
    log("route changed: $what ($oldScreenName -> $newScreenName)"); // it's just route activity log, don't forget to import 'dart:developer';
    final uri = Uri.parse(newScreenName ?? "");
    final routeName = uri.pathSegments.isNotEmpty ? uri.pathSegments.first : "";
    switch ("/$routeName") {
      case "/welcome"  : return setTitle("Welcome");
      case "/login"    : return setTitle("Login");
      case "/register" : return setTitle("Sign Up");
      // etc ...
    }
    setTitle("Not Found");
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    super.didPush(route, previousRoute);
    if (route is PageRoute && previousRoute is PageRoute) _setTitle("push", previousRoute, route);
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    super.didReplace(newRoute: newRoute, oldRoute: oldRoute);
    if (newRoute is PageRoute && oldRoute is PageRoute) _setTitle("replace", oldRoute, newRoute);
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    super.didPop(route, previousRoute);
    if (route is PageRoute && previousRoute is PageRoute) _setTitle("pop", route, previousRoute);
  }
}
```

**helpers.dart**

```
void setTitle([String? title]) async {
  Future.microtask(() {
    SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: "Your APP | ${title ?? 'Your Tagline'}",
      primaryColor: Colors.blue.value, // your app primary color
    ));
  });
}
```

finally, if you want to override title individually in specific page, do:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    setTitle("Custom Page Title");
  });
}
```