# Page title switches to Url once page loads?

Tags: html, flutter, firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I have two Flutter web projects:
`myurl.com`
and `business.myurl.com`

I added in Icons to both files, and the business site's title now changes from the title it should be, to the URL of the page after the page loads. I went over every character looking for the difference in my html files, but I can't find any mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The problem occurs in both debug mode and when hosted online.

Here is the `index.html` of the business site with the problem:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="My description here.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="My Title">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>

  <title>My Title</title>
 
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
```

I should also note right before this error I accidently deleted my projects `web` folder (instead of a Icon) and I restored it from the recycle bin, and everything seems to be the same. `flutter doctor` shows no issues found.

EDIT:
When I navigate from the home page it switches the page title to what the title is should be, if I pop back home the title is still correct. Just the first initial load of the page shows the URL as the title, until some navigation happens

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220989/how-can-you-set-title-and-icon-for-a-flutter-web-app/59246487) might have some info. Especially the highest voted answer specifically for setting the title.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran thanks but the issue wasn't setting the title, the issue was a bug where the set title was changing to the url after the page fully loaded (it would change back to the title after a navigation occurred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying, I couldn't find any good reason for this behavior and I'm going to guess it is a bug with Flutter web.

Anyways, here's a workaround fix to set the title again once it changes to the URL:
(`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`)

```
SystemChrome.setApplicationSwitcherDescription(ApplicationSwitcherDescription(
      label: 'MyTitle',
      primaryColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.value,
    ));
```